# Telegram Cannal view Counts not update

Tags: java, c#, android, telegram

I create telegram client with MProto Protocol, all things is good and work perfect but i have problem with update channel messages view `counter.after` i get message with `MProto.getChannelDialogs` i use `MProto.ReadHistory` for mark them read.

after i check unread message with `getChannelDialogs`, i see 0 but nobody seen added view counter of channel messages added any more.

***I use layer 40***

this is my code :

```
My.GetChannelDialogsAsync(new TLInt(0), new TLInt(100),
    (fghj) =>
    {
        var fg = fghj.Dialogs[0].UnreadCount;

        Log(" UnreadCount: " + fg.ToString());

        var chdialog = fghj.Dialogs[0] as TLDialogChannel;

        var chanll = chdialog.With as TLChannel;

        My.ReadHistoryAsync(chanll, new TLInt(int.MaxValue),
            (ReadHistoryRes) =>
            {
                Log("Read:" + ReadHistoryRes.Value);
            },
            (ReadHistoryErr) => Log("ReadHistoryAsync::" + ReadHistoryErr.Message.Value)
        );
    }
);
```

why not counter added my views?